# How Can I Make Ansible Download A File If It Doesn't Exist

Tags: ansible

I need to download the ansible tar from http://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/2.2.9/ and install it on multiple servers.

Rather than downloading the file on each host I would like to download the file on the playbook host then copy it to each host for install (to save bandwidth).

In my testing I have managed to copy the tar from the host to the servers

```
- name: Copy Cassandra
  copy: 
    src: "{{item}}" 
    dest: "{{tmp_dir}}"
  with_items:
    - "{{cassandra_tar}}"
```

However, I have manually put the cassandra tar in the right place before running the playbook.

How do I make ansible check if the file exists in the playbook host and only download the tar if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Please check the docs for [get_url](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/get_url_module.html) module. Pay attention to `force` option.

Comment: The same way you would do it on each target host, except that on localhost. I'm not sure where you see an obstacle.

Comment: The issue is that the playbook is executes on the target and not the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download on you host, specify a `delegate`, something like :

```
- name: Download Cassandra
  become: no
  get_url:
    url: "http://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/{{cassandra_version}}/{{cassandra_tar}}"
    dest: /tmp
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

`become: no` is to account for using become in the main `site.yaml` and causes ansible to use the playbook user to download the file to the host.

Comment: I believe you will want to add the "run_once: true" option to that task, or it will repeat the download (on localhost) for every host in the play.